# How to do a half-page turn under a fixed display item

Tags: positioning, movie15

Suppose you have a displayed item (in my case a video) at the top of a page and you want to have it present there for the next several pages. So you need to turn the bottom half page while the top half persists independently of the bottom part. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using beamer? article? We need a bit more details.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheDubacq  I prefer to use article.

Comment: I think you can't do that. That is automatically. But i'm not sure.